# Django local variable 'vaiable' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Buen día.
No eh podido solucionar este error "local variable '--' referenced before assignment", mi codigo es este:

**Vista:**

```
 def palcosSearch(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
     form = SearchPalco(request.POST)

     if form.is_valid(): 
         NamePalco = form.cleaned_data('palco')
         palcos = Palco.objects.filter(palcoName=NamePalco)        
 else:
    form=SearchPalco()
    palcos=None
 return render(request,'ExamenTemplates/palcosSearch.html',{"form": 
 form,"palcos":palcos})
```

**Modelo**

```
class Palco(models.Model):
Category = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
palcoName = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
capacity = models.IntegerField()
location =  models.CharField(max_length = 255)
class Meta:
    db_table = "Palco"

def __str__(self):
    return self.palcoName
```

**Forma**

```
class SearchPalco(forms.Form):
palco = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Palco',initial='',
                            widget=forms.Select(),
                             queryset=None)

def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(SearchPalco,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['palco'].widget.attrs['class']= 'form-control'
    self.fields['palco'].widget.attrs['placeholder']= 'Ingrese palco.'
    self.fields['palco'].queryset = 
    Palco.objects.values_list('palcoName', flat=True)
```

Se que el motivo es que no pasa la condición en la vista de    `is_valid()` pero no encuentro el porque.

Comment: Antes del primer if declara la variable polcas=None , en las nuevas versiones de Python y Django esto es obligatorio

Comment: @abulafia  si la quite sin darme cuenta disculpa

Comment: @JimyHendrixFalcónCárdenas Gracias! con esto se soluciono el error

Answer (score 0):

El código que muestras está mal indentado (seguramente un error al hacer el corta/pega) por lo que no es muy fiable aventurar conclusiones sobre el mismo.

Supongamos que la indentación correcta es la siguiente (lo que es una suposición razonable):

```
 def palcosSearch(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchPalco(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid(): 
            NamePalco = form.cleaned_data('palco')
            palcos = Palco.objects.filter(palcoName=NamePalco)        
    else:
        form=SearchPalco()
        palcos=None
    return render(request,'ExamenTemplates/palcosSearch.html',{"form": 
    form,"palcos":palcos})
```

Entonces fíjate. Si el método es POST, el primer `if` se cumple. Pero si después `form.is_valid()` fuese `False`, ese `if` anidado no se ejecuta, y entonces la variable `palcos` no se asigna. El `else:` pertenece al `if` más exterior, por lo que tampoco se ejecuta. Llegamos por tanto al `return` sin haber asignado nada a la variable `palcos`, pero el `return` referencia esa variable.

Por tanto tienes el error indicado: variable referenciada antes de haber sido asignada.

Esto lo puedes resolver de dos formas. Bien le das a la variable un valor por defecto antes del `if`, o bien se lo das en un `else` del `if` interno.

En cualquier caso esto no tiene nada qué ver con la última versión de python o Django, es lo habitual cuando intentas usar una variable que aún no tiene ningún valor.